# Which database should I use to store in real time my exact location from an Android application and then display it in my website (tracking system)?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb, nosql, backend

I'm kind of new at backend development, and I should to create a website (tracking) display the location of my phone, this location I have to retrieve from an android application.

My question is which database should I use? sql, nosql ?? mongoDB, Phpmyadmin !!

Answer (score 0):

Your use case seems to be suitable for time series in mongo, check here:https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/timeseries-collections/